# Why does my Python program not provide the square for both numbers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a calculator in Python and it gives the square just for the first number entered.

```
num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
operator = input("Enter an operator: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))



if operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif operator == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif operator == "^":
    print(num1 * num1) and print(num2 * num2)
else:
    print("Invalid operator")
```

Comment: `print(num1 * num1) and print(num2 * num2)` is not how you print two things in a row. `and` is a logical operator (which shortcircuits)

Comment: Please properly format your code. Paste it, select it, and then hit the code icon on the edit tool (or type `ctrl+k`)

Comment: `and` designates logical statement, if you want to print both numbers, use `print("{} {}".format(num1*num1, num2*num2))`

Comment: Dunno what your assignment is, but usually `n^m` means "`n` to the power of `m`," not "`n` squared and `m` squared."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses [short-circuiting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/short-circuiting-techniques-python/) in logical conditions - in simple words if it determines that there is enough info so that the whole condition is `True` or `False` it won't continue executing the rest of the code in the condition statement - so in your case not all code you intended got executed.

A simple fix for your code to do what you want would be splitting up `print` statements:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
operator = input("Enter an operator: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))



if operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif operator == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif operator == "^":
    print(num1 * num1)
    print(num2 * num2)
else:
    print("Invalid operator")
```